# Why is pickle.dump is not writing a new file (the code executes without an error)?

Tags: python, pickle

```
filename1 = 'random_forest.pkl'
filename2 = 'naive_bayes.pkl'
pickle.dump(r_clf,open(filename1,"wb"))
pickle.dump(clf,open(filename2,"wb"))
```

This has worked previously. After i made some changes, it just runs and do nothing.
I'm new to pickle, plz help me guys!

Comment: Try to add full path to your files instead of relative filenames.

Comment: Make sure to close the files so they are flushed to disk.

Comment: @YevheniiM.: It's writing to the files, so it'll open them in whatever the working directory is. Odds are the OP just isn't looking in the right (write?) place.

Comment: @ShadowRanger this is what I wanted to hint to the OP.

Comment: @YevheniiM.: I'm not sure it's possible to hint at "working directory != script directory" issues. People who didn't grow up in a command line environment don't understand the concept of a working directory unless they're beaten over the head with it (not a knock on those people, it's just not a concept you need outside a CLI).

Comment: @MarkTolonen I tried closing too but my files aren't getting created. The odd thing is that the above syntax had worked perfectly for me before. But now nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Apparently the code works when i run it on jupyter notebook. I don't know why tho!

Answer (score 0):

try that

```py
import pickle

r_clf = None
clf = None

filename1 = 'random_forest.pkl'
filename2 = 'naive_bayes.pkl'

with open(filename1,"wb") as f1:
    pickle.dump(r_clf, f1)

with open(filename2,"wb") as f2:
    pickle.dump(clf, f2)
```

Comment: does it make a new file at least ?

Comment: no it doesn't do anything. The problem only exists on spyder tho. It did work when i run the same code on jupyter notebook.